# VIM -- (вставка) ВИЗУАЛЬНЫЙ РЕЖИМ --

Tags: vim

С недавних пор не могу в putty вставить содержимое из буфера обмена - при нажатии правой клавиши мыши срабатывает выделение.
Написано:  VIM -- (вставка) ВИЗУАЛЬНЫЙ РЕЖИМ --

Как вернуть обычный режим вставки?
Судя по всему такая фигня появилась после установки Иксов.

Comment: по умолчанию x-сервер передаёт содержимое XA_PRIMARY при нажатии средней кнопки мыши.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://www.jacoballred.com/web-dev/enabling-mouse-support-i.../

Не знаю как не нашел сразу в справке vim прямо на первой страницу есть это:

```
Jump to a subject:  Position the cursor on a tag (e.g. bars) and hit CTRL-].
   With the mouse:  ":set mouse=a" to enable the mouse (in xterm or GUI).
                    Double-click the left mouse button on a tag, e.g. bars.
        Jump back:  Type CTRL-T or CTRL-O (repeat to go further back).
```

помоголо:
в конец /home/user/.vimrc
set mouse=
(после равно ничего не вносить)

пока изучал вопрос еще вставка без мыши "Shift + Ins"

мне посоветовали еще (мышку юзать с шифтом):
 Instead use Shift+middle-click to paste X selection
это сам уже не пробовал

Answer (score 0):

Вставка через `p`
Если нужен буфер системы, то `"+p`, так же можно использовать любой буфер вместо `+` и копирование через `y` осуществляется в соответствии с теми же правилами

З.ы.
Использовать мышь в виме, то же самое что копать огород ложкой. Смысл и много фич просто-напросто улетучиваются

Comment: О том и речь что с установкой иксов в vim  включилась мышь, пришлось отключить. p  тут не поможет поскольку нужен был буфер винды, а в режиме визуальной вставки вставляется только то что непосредственно на сервере.

Comment: @Dijey нет "режима визуальной вставки". Есть режим визуального выделения. Чтобы вставить из системного буфера нужно последовательно нажать `"+p`